# Does erasing my lost Google mobile remotely delete my Google cloud data as well?

Tags: factory-reset

I lost my  phone abroad. I want to use Google's 'find my phone/erase my phone' function to wipe all my Google data (account on my phone) remotely. HOWEVER, I can't figure out how to prevent this from erasing all the data/media in my Google drive/Google Photo's. Obviously I only want the account erased from the phone, and NOT my cloud data...Am I worrying for nothing? I'm quite hesitant to erase my phone now...Anyone with knowledge on this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your cloud data is safe, so is other data. This can be lost only if you **delete** your account. See Google help [Delete your Google Account - Google Account Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32046?hl=en)

When you are erasing data as described by you, only the data on the phone is erased. Your account is not deleted

You can get a new device and use the same account to backup and have access to whatever was saved on the cloud

Comment: Thanks man, this is reassuring insight! i'll go ahead with the erase option immediately then...

Comment: You can choose any of the answers that worked for you to be marked as "accepted" by ticking the green arrow next to it. This is the way of saying that it worked for you and thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your worrying for nothing, your lost phone will be wiped by its new owner if they intend on using it. They will be able to connect your phone to a PC and have a look at your personal effects ... music, pics etc, but not your account information. Hopefully you don't have any TXT or docs that contain usernames and passwords like some people do.

Chances of your phone still being connected to a network for you to wipe remotely are slim.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Brad. I hope the new owner will connect the phone to some or other network at some stage, at which point the authorisation of the erase function should (in theory) kick in automatically...Regards